# Parsing text in parens using JParsec

Tags: java, parsing, dsl, jparsec

I'm writing a parser for a DSL that uses the syntax `(nodeHead: nodeBody)`. The problem is that `nodeBody` may contain parens, at some cases.
The `between` operator of JParsec should have been a good solution, yet the following code fails:

```
public void testSample() {
    Parser<Pair<String,String>> sut = Parsers.tuple(Scanners.IDENTIFIER.followedBy(Scanners.among(":")),
            Scanners.ANY_CHAR.many().source()
            ).between(Scanners.among("("), Scanners.among(")"));
    sut.parse("(hello:world)");
}
```

It does not fail when I change `ANY_CHAR` to `IDENTIFIER`, so I assume the issue here is that the second parser in the tuple is too greedy. Alternatively, can I make JParsec apply the between parsers before it applies the body?

Any ideas are very much appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time I was asking, seems like there was no way to do that. However, a [github fork-and-pull](https://github.com/abailly/jparsec/pull/14) later, there is: `reluctantBetween()`.

Big thanks to @abailly on the fast response.

Answer (score -1):

If the syntax rule is that the last character will always be ")", you could probably do:

```
static <T> Parser<T> reluctantBetween(
    Parser<?> begin, Parser<T> parser, Parser<?> end) {
  Parser<?> terminator = end.followedBy(eof());
  return between(begin, terminator.not().next(parser).many(), terminator);
}
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions with questions, leave it as a comment

Comment: The rule is that the last character has to be ")". Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer with a code snippet. I didn't verify it but it's the idea.